# How can I call programmatically a product description in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento, zend-framework

I am new in Magento 1.7.0.2

I would like to make some **custom html divs** inside the **product's phtml page** and to call

1) the **product description** , 
2) another div with **product tags** and 
3) another div with **reviews of this specific product**.
4) another div which will **contain a specific cms page** (ask about this product)

Do you know how should I write php inside each div in order to call these 
specific attributes of a product in Magento 1.7.0.2 ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i am giving your code to do with your above specification you can set it in to your html

**1. Product description**

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);

echo $_product->getShortDescription(); //product's short description
echo $_product->getDescription(); // product's long description
```

**2. product tags**

```
$model=Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $tags= $model->getResourceCollection()
        ->addPopularity()
        ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
        ->addProductFilter(PRODUCT_ID)
        ->setFlag('relation', true)
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->setActiveFilter()
        ->load();

    if(isset($tags) && !empty($tags)):
        foreach($tags as $tag):
            echo '<span class="tag">'.$tag->getName().'</span>';
        endforeach;
```

**3. Product Reviews**

```
$productId = $product->getId();
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getResourceCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder()
->addRateVotes();
```

**4.contain a specific cms page**

I would like to suggest you if you want to display product specific content you can create block for product and in `phtml` file you can call like below

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your-block-id')->toHtml();
```

Also you can refer [detail page](http://jeremyhixon.com/adding-static-block-phtml-files-magento/)

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: this is the error Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\design\frontend\dnhresearch\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml on line 167

Comment: line 167 is like this<?php $productId = $product->getId();
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getResourceCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder()
->addRateVotes(); ?>

Comment: you have to get product_id in for review if you wann to test pass some  any one the product id with static one like product_id =1

Comment: I am in a page with a specific product id.But How should I get it? Thanks very much for the help

Comment: I want also to see them in my page not just get them...Any suggestion? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @kost, Will pls vote up so some one can trust our answer. you can set logic in you phtml file with the return array or value.

Comment: How can I set logic in my phtml example? Could you give me an example of what you mean ? Thanks